# Персонаж застревает на платформе. Unity

Tags: unity3d

Делаю первую небольшую игру самостоятельно. Есть вот такой метод Flip, отвечающий за поворот персонажа. Есть платформа, на которой он стоит. Метод Flip, естественно, находится в Update. Персонаж не может упасть с платформы, как будто какие то границы его не выпускают, когда Flip вызывается. Убираю Flip из кода игры - персонаж падает спокойно с платформы. В чем здесь проблема? Unity 2D

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D Player;
    float speed = 5;
    float move;
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Движение героя 
       
        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Player.velocity = new Vector2(move, 0) * speed;
        Flip();
    }

    // Разворот героя
    void Flip()                                                           
    {
        if (move < 0)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
            


        }
        else if (move > 0)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
            
        }
        
    }


    // Прыжок 
    void Jump()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не правильно пишете else if. Надо не писать внутри else, а просто else if { код }

Comment: Исправил, спасибо. Даже не заметил эту глупую ошибку. Но что с персонажем? Он так и застревает

Comment: Скиньте как у вас реализован класс, который висит на Player. В частности - кусок где там логика движения реализована через velocity. Возможно, еще возникнет необходимость посмотреть как у вас реализовано "спрыгивание" с платформы...

Comment: Весь код добавил в вопрос. Спрыгивания с платформы нет. На герое же висит гравитация. У платформы и него самого есть коллайдеры. поэтому он должен падать. Но он доходит до края и все, дальше не идет. Код с rotation вроде был правильным, но сейчас я пытаюсь метод Flip прописать через sprite renderer

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ты жестко задаешь вектор движения, ограничивая перемещение по оси y нулём и уничтожая тем самым влияние других внешних сил (той же гравитации). Если на пути у игрока появится препятствие - в твоём случае он пройдёт насквозь, несмотря на коллайдеры.

Вместо `Player.velocity = new Vector2(move, 0) * speed;`
используй `Player.AddForce(new Vector2(move, 0) * speed)`.
Таким образом ты добавишь к сумме прочих сил свою - движущую вбок.

У AddForce есть дополнительный аргумент, отвечающий за способы приложения силы - постоянное, ускоряющее, взрывное и тп
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html